# How to improve this queries performance by indexing properly?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, t-sql, indexing

Hi here i have a query and i need to improve the performance of this query.Can anyone suggest me like how to convert the clustered index scan to index seek.

```
DECLARE @now DateTime;      
DECLARE @lastweekstart DateTime;      
DECLARE @lastweekend DateTime;      


SET @now = getDate();      
SET @lastweekstart = DATEADD(      
                 DD,      
                 -(DATEPART(DW, @now - 14) - 1),      
                 @now - 14);       
SET @lastweekend = DATEADD(      
               DD,      
               7 - (DATEPART(DW, @now - 14)),      
               @now - 14);      



SELECT Distinct CHINFO.CHILDID,
        COUNT(*)  as PREVIOUSWEEKSACCIDENTS       
FROM  BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO       
JOIN  BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE       
       ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID        
JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP       
        ON  CHE.EVENTID = CHEP.EVENTID           
WHERE (CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT' OR (CHE.TYPE = 'POTTYBREAK' AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS'       
        AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'))           
        AND CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN @lastweekstart AND @lastweekend       
        GROUP BY CHINFO.CHILDID
```

[image]

Any suggestion????????????

EDIT:

**Primary Keys:**

TableName --> ColumnName

CHILDINFORMATION-->ChildId

CHILDEVENTS-->EventId

CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES-->EventPropertyId

**Foreign Keys:**

CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES-->Here EventId is the foreign key reference of CHILDEVENTS table

CHILDEVENTS-->Here ChildId is the foreign key reference of CHILDINFORMATION table

**NonClustered Indexes:**

CHILDINFORMATION-->No nonclustered indexes

ChildEventProperities-->IX_CHILDEVENTproperities_EventId-->EventID

ChildEvents-->IX_ChildEvents_Type-->Type

ChildEvents-->IX_ChildEvents_Type_AddDate-->Type,AddDate

Comment: Did you try anything yet?

Comment: i have tried creating indexes using different combinations but no luck

Comment: I'm still learning much of this, but wouldn't it also depend on your stats?  Are they up to date or set to auto?  Also how many rows are we talking about?  If there are just a few rows, I imagine that the optimiser will choose to do a scan instead of a seek.  Maybe a scan is the optimum method?

Answer (score 0):

Try replace your JOIN to LEFT JOIN? and remove DISTINCT if you using GROUP BY

```
SELECT CHINFO.CHILDID,
        COUNT(*) AS PREVIOUSWEEKSACCIDENTS       
FROM  BKA.CHILDINFORMATION CHINFO       
LEFT JOIN  BKA.CHILDEVENTS CHE       
       ON CHE.CHILDID = CHINFO.CHILDID        
LEFT JOIN BKA.CHILDEVENTPROPERITIES CHEP       
        ON  CHE.EVENTID = CHEP.EVENTID           
WHERE (CHE.TYPE = 'ACCIDENT' OR (CHE.TYPE = 'POTTYBREAK' AND CHEP.PROPERTY = 'SUCCESS'       
        AND CHEP.PROPERTYVALUE = 'FALSE'))           
        AND CHE.ADDDATE BETWEEN @lastweekstart AND @lastweekend       
        GROUP BY CHINFO.CHILDID
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a single column nonclustered index on CHILDEVENTS.ADDDATE. Your current composite index could be thrown off by the "or" or the lack of selectivity on those two TYPEs. You might get some improvement if you add TYPE as the second column of the index.

Now if you're just starting up this system and don't have any significant data in the CHILDEVENTS table, then it's going to scan.